# React Native, Dynamically adjust scrollIndicatorInsets of ScrollView / FlatList

Tags: react-native, dynamic, position, scrollview

Is it possible to change the values of scrollIndicatorInsets in React Native dynamically. I have tried doing this using a variable that is adjusted as the screen scrolls but am getting an invariant violation.

In the example below, the idea is to change the position of the top inset of the Scroll View as the user scrolls so that the scroll bar does not cover the header until that header has scrolled out of view.

**Var set at Render**

```
VSScroll = this.state.scrollY.interpolate({
            inputRange: [0, 88, 89],
            outputRange: [144, 88, 88]
        });
```

**Return**

```
<Animated.ScrollView
    scrollIndicatorInsets={[VSScroll, 0, 52, 0]}
    onScroll={Animated.event([
                    { nativeEvent: {
                    contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY }
                    }
                }],
                { useNativeDriver: true }
            )} >

... etc.
```

The variable VSScroll is causing an invariant violation even though console log checks show it is generating the number wanted to create the inset.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible but scrollIndicatorInset will to work with the native scroll event. It will however accept a variable and therefore can accept a state.

So,

**Create a state in the Constructor**

```
this.state= {
    insetOffset: 140,
}
```

**Add a listener to the onScroll Animated Event with it's own event bound to a function (eg. *handleOnScroll*)**

```
onScroll={
    Animated.event(
        [{ nativeEvent: { contentOffset: { y: this.state.scrollY } } }],
        { 
            listener: (event) => this.handleOnScroll(event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y), 
            useNativeDriver: true, 
        }
    )
}
```

**Then use the function to return the desired value to the state. (Place the function between the Constructor and the Render.**

```
handleOnScroll = event => {
        var offset = 140 - event;
        if(event > 98){
            offset = 140 - 98
        }
        this.setState({
            insetOffset: offset
        })
    }
```

**Change the value of the scrollIndicatorInset to include the state**

```
<Animated.ScrollView
    scrollIndicatorInsets={{top: this.state.insetOffset, left: 0, bottom: 52, right:0}}
```

QED..

Comment: As much as this works it is far from an efficient means with which to do it. Setting a state change on each scroll event is not going to give good performance as the entire component will re-render on each change. The best way to do this is with setNativeProps. I will post full code when I have a moment. Reply here if you want it (given that no one else seems interested in these matters).